# Composite video (one channel) to RF input of an old CRT TV

Tags: analog, video, crt

I want to convert HDMI signal to RF signal(antenna input) for my old TV (AV is input broken). If I connect Composite video (one channel) to  RF input of an old CRT TV, does it work? Audio to TV is not required.

Comment: No, of course it won't work.

Comment: No, you need an RF modulator. They used to be sold with games consoles that had composite out.

Comment: Are you planning to build and develop one from scratch or buy one?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't as simple as you might think. You need an HDMI receiver/decoder chip and a VGA/composite encoder/transmitter chip, both of which are readily available from vendors such as Analog Devices.

Then, you either need to convince the HDMI source to produce an SDTV-compatible signal (interlaced) through the EDID data that you send it, or you need to do an explicit scan-rate conversion between the two chips mentioned above, which requires a couple more chips.

Finally, you need an RF modulator to convert the baseband composite output of the encoder chip to an RF signal that the TV can receive.

Or you could just buy a box that performs this function, but that would be off-topic here.

Comment: Is there a way to change the aspect ratio in the setup u suggest

Comment: Yes, that's lumped in with the "scan conversion" that I mentioned, which covers parameters such as horizontal and vertical sync frequencies, progressive vs. interlaced scanning and aspect ratio.

Answer (score -1):

Would connecting this:
[image: HDMI->composite]
in series with this:
[image: composite->coax]
solve OPs problem?

If yes, crack them open and see how they are made. HDMI->composite should be one big IC. RF generation is more tricky.

Comment: This does NOT do what the OP needs. It produces a 64QAM *digital RF* signal that is not compatible with an analog TV. In any case, we do not support shopping questions here, so this answer is not appropriate.

Comment: @DaveTweed. I'll edit it to an analog counterpart. Also, how about shopping answers? Otherwise, flag the question?

Comment: The question is ambiguous -- it could be a design question (on-topic, but not very practical) or a shopping question (off-topic). That's why answers need to focus on the former interpretation rather than the latter.

Comment: @DaveTweed. I see. I suggest to buy the two boxes, crack them open and get plenty of ideas and suggestions for how to implement it in a circuit for OP. It should answer many questions one might have.

Comment: Since composite signal and rf signal were referred as analog signal,  I was confused and had the question that probably they are same with different signal modulation frequency